keycloak-saml adapter multitenancy configured externally to the secured war
I would like to deploy my application.war into jboss/wildfly and configure it in a such way, that it will be using two different IdP. It can be done using multi-tenancy and multiple keycloak-saml.xml files.
I would like to have no specific configuration (no keycloak-saml.xml) in my application build (like 12factor app advises) and to have all SP/IdP related configuration inside standalone.xml configuration of application server.
When using single IdP, there is a way of not touching war file and secure it only using app server configuration.
I have tried to configure single IdP in a such way. It is working OK. I have set-up (the only thing in web.xml inside deployed war file) security context like this:
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/loginUsingSaml.jsp</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/loginUsingSaml2.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>login</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

This single SP/IdP configuration works. When I open my app, it will use its own (custom) login mechanism. When I open /loginUsingSaml.jsp page, it will (jboss and keycloak-saml adapter) redirect me to the IdP. After login, it redirect me back and application will recognize logged-in principal.
I would like to configure second IdP for my app, which will be used when openning /loginUsingSaml2.jsp address (or any other feasible approach).
My configure.cli passed to the jboss/wildfly looks like this:
# add saml extension/adapter for keycloak to application server
# originally these commands resides in bin/adapter-elytron-install-saml.cli (or in bin/adapter-install-saml.cli, when not using elytron)

if (outcome != success) of /extension=org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-subsystem:read-resource
    /extension=org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-subsystem/:add(module=org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-subsystem)
else
    echo Keycloak SAML Extension already installed, going to continue.
end-if
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=keycloak-saml:read-resource
    /subsystem=keycloak-saml:add
else
    echo Keycloak SAML Subsystem already installed, going to continue.
end-if


# my actual configuration (instead of using keycloak-saml.xml in WEB-INF of war, it is more flexible to do it on app server side)
# note, that SP entityID is http://localhost:8081/app/

/subsystem=keycloak-saml/secure-deployment=application.war/:add

/subsystem=keycloak-saml/secure-deployment=application.war/SP="http://localhost:8081/app/"/:add( \
    sslPolicy=NONE, \
    autodetectBearerOnly=true, \
    logoutPage="app/actions.jsp?app=&page=do_logout", \
)

/subsystem=keycloak-saml/secure-deployment=application.war/SP="http://localhost:8081/app/"/IDP="http://localhost:8005/realms/realm"/:add( \
    signatureAlgorithm=RSA_SHA256, \
    signatureCanonicalizationMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", \
    SingleSignOnService={ \
        signRequest=false, \
        validateResponseSignature=true, \
        validateAssertionSignature=false, \
        requestBinding=POST, \
        assertionConsumerServiceUrl="http://localhost:8081/app/saml", \
        bindingUrl=http://localhost:8005/realms/realm/protocol/saml }, \
    SingleLogoutService={ \
        signRequest=false, \
        signResponse=false, \
        validateRequestSignature=true, \
        validateResponseSignature=true, \
        requestBinding=POST, \
        responseBinding=POST, \
        postBindingUrl=http://localhost:8005/realms/realm/protocol/saml, \
        redirectBindingUrl=http://localhost:8005/realms/realm/protocol/saml } \
)

